# Can a VPN server also act as a client?

Tags: vpn, openvpn

I have only one system with me... is there someway that I can setup a VPN server in the device and the same device can act as a client?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. Your question doesn't make sense. Your question sounds like: "I am standing at the train station A. Can I buy buy a train ticket for going from A to A?" There may be reasons for doing what you want but it is not obvious. Please **edit**you question and add more details on what you want to achieve by doing this.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, server and client software are different software installations.

Having both active at the same time can be an issue. The client likely needs to use a dynamic port and the server needs to use a fixed port as to avoid conflicts. And you want to use a different node for each

- OpenVPN always binds to port 1194 with both server and client mode.
- The option in openvpn would be `--dev-node {node}` for the node.